# How can I make images responsively resize to the largest width possible before overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I am designing a scrolling (horizontally) gallery with a long string of photos left to right. They are of varying heights, some vertically long, some horizontally long. I'd like to only alter the width, and keep the same aspect ratio for each photo. This was easy to code for a standard size laptop screen, but it does not function properly on screens with different sizes.

How can I make the photos update responsively so that the vertical images are as tall as the remaining space on the page?

Currently, my issue is the fact that the gallery sits higher than the bottom of the page.

I am using vws to set the width so far, and still having this issue. I tried the flexbox solution using flex-grow to no avail.

To put it simply,

How can I responsively update image widths to fill the remaining space on the page?

Answer (score 2):

Apply `height: 100%; width: auto;` to your images. That will keep each image's aspect ratio intact while making them uniform height so the scrolling thingy looks nice.

```css
.scroller {
  height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-wrapper img {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroller">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/220/300" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/220/220" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/160/400" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/210/150" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/130/300" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/220" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/100/200" />
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/90" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like how you explained the easy props but not the one that does the heavy lifting, flex?

Comment: @Pablo yeah true... but the question didnt supply a slider so I whipped up my own. Flexbox is automatic for me these days so... ;)

Comment: I agree `flex` is the bomb and you got my upvote :)  However, it is still new or unknown to those getting started.